# backlight:acpi_video0: No such device

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, backlight

I installed for two weeks Arch Linux. As Display Manager I have installed LightDM.

For some days I get an error durning system boot from lightdm.service and systemd-backlight@.service.

I see only a black monitor and must login about an other tty.

The the log from systemd-backlight@.service says, I don't have the device acpi_video0.

```
-- Reboot --
Sep 19 13:30:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
Sep 19 13:30:39 markus-pc systemd-backlight[453]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video0': No such device
Sep 19 13:30:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 19 13:30:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
Sep 19 13:30:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 19 13:30:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The Arch Linux [Wiki Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#systemd-backlight_service) describe that every device has an directory in `/sys/class/backlight`, but I don't have one.

```
markus@markus-pc:~$ ls -la /sys/class/backlight/
insgesamt 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 19. Sep 13:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 51 root root 0 19. Sep 13:53 ..
```

How I can find out which graphic card I actually use, when I start my desktop environment cinnamon and tell the systemd-backlight@.service that he must use this graphic card for displaying LightDM?

Here are my LightDM errors.

```
-- Reboot --
Sep 19 13:49:19 markus-pc systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Sep 19 13:49:19 markus-pc systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Sep 19 13:49:37 markus-pc systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Sep 19 13:49:37 markus-pc systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Sep 19 13:49:38 markus-pc lightdm[836]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 19 13:49:39 markus-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and add the below parameters to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
> ```

Do not forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: Although this removed the error message, this broke my screen brightness control, which was then stuck at maximum brightness.

Comment: That worked for me too and  it didn't remove the capability to adjust the screen brightness as normal afterwards. Works great! Thanks! :)